# WSO2 Enterprise Store - how can I add mobile apps?

Tags: wso2, wso2-es, wso2-iot

I'm trying out the beta/unreleased code for EMM 2.0 (which I believe is now MDM) and I undestand that the mobile app store and publisher function have been moved to Enterprise Store, however I'm unable to see/add mobile apps - I only see Gadgets and Sites.

I was looking for the source in case I missed the plugin, but at https://github.com/wso2/carbon-store/tree/master/features/extensions I only see Gadgets and Sites.

**Can someone tell me how to enable mobile apps and/or point me to the mobile app plugin source?**

FYI, I installed ES from http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-store/ and also master branch from the following:

- https://github.com/wso2/product-mdm.git
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt-plugins.git
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WSO2 App Manager](http://wso2.com/products/app-manager/),

Please read this doc to integrate it with WSO2 EMM
https://docs.wso2.com/display/APPM100/Mobile+Apps+Configurations

WSO2 is working on integrating app management features with WSO2 EMM 2.0.0. Device and App Management both features will be shipped with EMM 2.0.0 once it is released.